# Animating height in WIndows Phone

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, animation, windows-phone

I have a grid containing two elements, a search form  and a custom UC to show items. When my page loads, the viewer control is hidden. I ant to animate it in with a storyboard when a button on the search form is clicked. I'm stuck at the `To=...` part of the animation. I want to animate it to the height of the parent container and have it slid up from the bottom. Is this possible?

For reference, this is my tree structure:

**Page resources:**

```
<Storyboard x:Name="animateViewSlide" Storyboard.TargetName="SearchForm" >
        <DoubleAnimation  Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" To="???" Duration="100"/>
</Storyboard>
```

**Control body:**

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid x:Name="SearchForm" Margin="6,6,6,70">
    <uc:AwesomeViewer x:Name="awesomeView" Awesomeness="{Binding SelectedAwesomeThing}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I did figure out a bit better way of doing this, instead of using the Margin to step through the animation, just animate the Y axis with a `TranslateTransform` like;

```
<Grid x:Name="ItemToMove" 
            Visibility="{Binding Condition, Converter={StaticResource boolVisConv}}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="30,0,0,-32" Opacity="0">
                <Grid.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform x:Name="notified" Y="40" />
                </Grid.RenderTransform>
                    <Grid.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Grid.Loaded">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="notified" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y">
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.25" Value="0" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ItemToMove" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.55" Value="1" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Grid.Triggers>
```

**END UPDATE**

Your trouble is going to stem from trying to animate an automatically calculated value (`Height`) so I would scrap that idea unless you want to use hard coded size values on your Parents/Children or just assume for example that if the app is restricted to Portrait Mode only....then your "To" value is 800px, except I imagine that's not what you're looking for.

Now then, you would usually hope you could just feed the rendered size into your "To" value, like maybe via `To="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=LayoutRootOROTHERParentContainer}"` right? Yet nay, that won't work either...

So while someone else may have a better way, the only way I've found is to instead leave the Auto calculated sizes alone to do their thing, and instead animate a stepping of the object `Margin` via `ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames` which when paired with an `Opacity` transition via `DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames` actually looks quite nice, except it will add a bunch of additional XAML for the process. So as a concept you might try something more like this (however if you come across a better solution, I'd sure like to know it also. As a designer for a living, I run into this relatively often.)

Concept Example;

(The Storyboard)

```
<Storyboard x:Name="Kaboom">
    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Margin)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                <Thickness>0,750,0,0</Thickness>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                <Thickness>0,600,0,0</Thickness>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                <Thickness>0,550,0,0</Thickness>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                <Thickness>0,500,0,0</Thickness>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                <Thickness>0,450,0,0</Thickness>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                <Thickness>0,400,0,0</Thickness>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.7">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                <Thickness>0,350,0,0</Thickness>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.8">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                <Thickness>0,300,0,0</Thickness>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.9">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                <Thickness>0,250,0,0</Thickness>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                <Thickness>0,200,0,0</Thickness>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.1">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                <Thickness>0,150,0,0</Thickness>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.2">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                <Thickness>0,100,0,0</Thickness>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.3">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                <Thickness>0,50,0,0</Thickness>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.4">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                <Thickness>0</Thickness>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="0.01"/>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.6" Value="1"/>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

A quick adhoc example of the concept in action;

```
<Grid Height="800" Width="480" x:Name="ParentContainer">
            <!-- Your SearchForm thingy with its funky margins already set like your example -->
            <Rectangle Margin="6,6,6,70" Fill="Green" />
            <Button Height="100" Width="100" Content="Click Me!" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                 <!-- Quick button to show it in action -->
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                            <ei:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource Kaboom}"/>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </Button>
            <!-- Your Awesomeness -->
            <Border x:Name="border" Width="300" Background="Blue" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,800,0,0" Opacity="0">
                <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Text="OH&#10;&#10;SNAP!!!&#10;&#10;Say&#10;&#10;WHAAA??" 
                            TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            FontSize="40" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White"/>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
```

Anyway, probably not exactly what you're hoping for, but is an effective alternative especially with a little tweaking unless like I said, you want to hardcode your object sizes so you have something viable to set your "To" value to...which, in the case of a phone that's restricted to the standard 800x480 Portrait Mode Only you may very well want to. However if you don't have that option, I've pulled off some pretty nifty designs using this method instead.

Hope this helps and best of luck!

Comment: That makes sense and the margin is an excellent idea. Thanks for the thorough answer.